# Create a datetime column in SQL Server 2008 with default value as current timestamp UTC

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am creating a table in SQL Server 2008 like this:

```
create table Dummy
(
   id int,
   status int,
   node_id varchar(512),
   createdDTTM datetime NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

However I want to specify a UTC timezone as default. I know in postgreSQL we have something like `createdDTTM TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (now() at time zone 'utc')`

Can we do similar thing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For times with timezone information, use [`DATETIMEOFFSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) in SQL Server (**2008** and newer):

```
create table dbo.Dummy
(
   id int,
   status int,
   node_id varchar(512),
   createdDTTM DateTimeOffset NOT NULL default SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
);
```

Using the [`SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx) you're getting the default current date and time as `DATETIMEOFFSET` (in the local timezone your server is located in) from SQL Server.

Or maybe you're looking for [`SYSUTCDATETIME()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630387.aspx) instead which gives you the current date and time in UTC format? This works just fine with `DATETIME2(n)` or `DATETIMEOFFSET` columns (in SQL Server **2008** and newer, I'd recommend *not* to use `DATETIME` anymore)

Comment: Perfect. I used SYSUTCDATETIME() as default with DATETIME2. While inserting the values in the table, I take care of inserting them in UTC format only.